# Problem visualizing .json in the browsers (Opera, Mozzila, Chrome)

Tags: export, blend4web

I have problem to visualize my scene in the browser.

I have blender4web and I'm doing this :
 1. exporting to json
 2. Open browser and put the link `http://localhost:6687/apps_dev/folder/file.html`

Then I get this:
[image]

Even turning off the firewall still same, I checked with others websites and they are working well.

I hope some one can help me please.

Comment: is ur internet working i mean other website working did u try

Comment: Is your server started ? https://www.blend4web.com/media/img_article/107/rect4179-1-4.jpg?v=

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Blend4Web, not Blender.

Comment: 1) Yes, internet its working well with others websites..   2) Thanks I'm checking the link right now.

Comment: Not sure if you'll be able to get any quality answers here, maybe you'll get a faster response over at [Blend4Web Forum](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/) since its where most devs hang out.